# More ImageView on TabActivity

Tags: android, imageview, tabactivity

It's my first post, and I hope I have searched well before I post.

I have created my first app studying many examples and tutorials. My app has a tabbed activity with swipe and it does function well.

I have two imageviews, one in one tab and the second in a second tab. When i write the public void imageclick to open a new activity with Intent, each image calls the same activity, but it should open different activity for different image.

I'm not able to set Findviewbyid to indicate which image I'm clicking.

```
public class welcome extends ActionBarActivity implements android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener{

private ViewPager tabsviewPager;
private ActionBar mActionBar;
private Tabsadapter mTabsAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    tabsviewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tabspager);

    mTabsAdapter = new Tabsadapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    tabsviewPager.setAdapter(mTabsAdapter);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab friendstab = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("Lo Staff").setTabListener(this);
    Tab publicprofiletab = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("La Storia").setTabListener(this);
    Tab communitytab = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText("Creazioni").setTabListener(this);

    getSupportActionBar().addTab(friendstab);
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(publicprofiletab);
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(communitytab);


    //This helps in providing swiping effect for v7 compat library
    tabsviewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}


   // Intent creat = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), collezioni.class);
    //startActivity(creat);



public void imageClick (View view) {
    Intent creat = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),collezioni.class);
    startActivity(creat);
}



@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab selectedtab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tabsviewPager.setCurrentItem(selectedtab.getPosition()); //update tab position on tap
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry...but i have solved using switch case statement.
I didn't know how use it, but triyng i'm was able to use.
I hope this will be helpful

```
public void imageClick (View view) {
    ImageView imgStaff = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgStaff);
    ImageView imgCat = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCatalog);
    switch (view.getId()){

        case(R.id.imgCatalog):
            Intent creat = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),collezioni.class);
            startActivity(creat);

        case(R.id.imgStaff):
                Intent mTouch = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MultiTouchAct.class);
                startActivity(mTouch);


    }

}
```